# an uncaught error while exporting database using mysqldump

Tags: php, mysql

This is the error I'm getting when running my code.

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function close() in C:\xampp\htdocs\qtqt\admin\db-backup.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\qtqt\admin\db-backup.php on line 15

This is the code ([from github](https://gist.github.com/famoser/c94968775339d4d57770e73c4b973a7b?fbclid=IwAR1jenqy5k3tkjLbzTK9mIj_GbiKJolHqPVHMmCYflEy7HxffPVAVu-1Gpw))

The code generates a mydata.sql file but it is empty.

```
<?php
$filename = 'database/mydata.sql';
$database   = 'stock';
$user   = 'root';
$password   = '';
$host = 'localhost';
/**
 * DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
 */
$fp = @fopen( $filename, 'w+' );
if( !$fp ) {
    echo 'Impossible to create <b>'. $filename .'</b>, please manually create one and assign it full write privileges: <b>777</b>';
    exit;
}
close( $fp );
$command = 'mysqldump --opt -h '. $host .' -u '. $user .' -p'. $password .' '. $database .' > '. $filename;
exec( $command, $output = array(), $worked );
switch( $worked ) {
    case 0:
        echo 'Database <b>'. $database .'</b> successfully exported to <b>'. $filename .'</b>';
        break;
    case 1:
        echo 'There was a warning during the export of <b>'. $database .'</b> to <b>'. $filename .'</b>';
        break;
    case 2:
        echo 'There was an error during import.'
            . 'Please make sure the import file is saved in the same folder as this script and check your values:'
            . '<br/><br/><table>'
            . '<tr><td>MySQL Database Name:</td><td><b>'. $database .'</b></td></tr>'
            . '<tr><td>MySQL User Name:</td><td><b>'. $user .'</b></td></tr>'
            . '<tr><td>MySQL Password:</td><td><b>NOTSHOWN</b></td></tr>'
            . '<tr><td>MySQL Host Name:</td><td><b>'. $host .'</b></td></tr>'
            . '<tr><td>MySQL Import Filename:</td><td><b>'. $filename .'</b></td>'
            . '</tr></table>'
        ;
        break;
}
```

Comment: What should `close()` do? Is it defined somewhere? (Should probably be `fclose()`)

Comment: it's not defined anywhere, I tried your code and got an error.

>fclose() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given

Comment: Change `close($fp);` to `fclose($fp);`.

Comment: Well, yes, thought it was clear to change the function name but keep the parameters. See @Dave's comment

Comment: @kerbholz sorry,I didn't know that

Comment: I've left a comment for the author on github.

Comment: that solved it, thankyou, but I got another error

>Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\qtqt\admin\db-backup.php on line 17

should I close this question and ask another one or can I ask you to help me throughout the whole process?

Comment: @Dave thanks, that would help beginners/amateurs like me.